# How to update only provided properties of a pre-existing model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, forms, model-view-controller, model, modelstate

When binding to a model, is it possible to provide a model from the database (already populated with its values), and then update that model using only what the web request provides?

For example, if I have this model:

```
public class Dog {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Owner {get; set;}
}
```

And that model could be populated from the database so that:

```
Dog.Name == "Rolo"
Dog.Owner == "Matt"
```

And I get a web request with the following parameters:

```
?name=Max
```

Then what I want to do is to provide that already populated model and only update the "Name" property.

The resulting object would be:

```
Dog.Name == "Max"
Dog.Owner == "Matt"
```

The Owner property would already be populated from the database and I don't have to do any copying of values, any additional mapping, etc.

How would one achieve this scenario using ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

When updating the dog's name, you'd want to pass the whole dog model, which includes the DogId back to the controller. That way you can query for the dog record in the database and update accordingly. The following example uses entity framework

```
public class Dog
{
   public int DogId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Owner { get; set; }
} 


[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDog(Dog model)
{
      if(!ModelState.IsValid)
          return View(model);

      var dbDog = await db.Dogs.SingleAsync(x => x.DogId = model.DogId);

      // ! at the beginning is shorthand for if the condition is false
      // this is just a shorter way of doing the other example below 
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name))
      {
          dbDog.Name = model.Name;
      }

      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Owner))
      {
          // model.Owner is null or an empty string so we don't want to 
          // update. We can leave this blank
      }
      else
      {
         // model.Owner has a value in it so we will update
         dbDog.Owner = model.Owner
      }

      // you can update more properties here if you wish, or ignore them
      // dbDog.Owner = model.Owner

      await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

      return View(model);
}
```

If you didn't want to pass the whole model back, you can pass your model.Name like you are doing but you would also want to include the model.DogId so you know which record from the database you want to update.

UpdateDog?name=Max&dogId=4

Hope this helps.

// AutoMapper Implementation based on comment
You would need to create a Mapping Profile, something like:

```
using AutoMapper;

public class DogProfile : Profile
{
    public DogProfile()
    {
       CreateMap<DogViewModel, Dog>()
          .ForMember(destination => destination.Owner, options => options.Condition(source => string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Owner))
          .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.Condition(source => string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Name));
    }
}
```

Then in your UpdateDog ActionResult you can try:

using AutoMapper;

```
public class DogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public DogsController(IMapper _mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDog(DogViewModel viewModel)
    {
          if(!ModelState.IsValid)
              return View(viewModel);

          var dbDog = await db.Dogs.SingleAsync(x => x.DogId = viewModel.DogId);

          dbDog = _mapper.Map<Dog>(viewModel)

          await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

          return View(model);
    }
}
```

Also, not sure how you're using AutoMapper but you may need to include the line in the snippet below inside your Startup.cs file if you have one:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddMvc();

       // Add this line 
       services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get how to do that, and I appreciate the comment. But what if I only want to update certain properties and I only want to do so if those properties are posted in the request?

Comment: Hi Matt, I updated the answer. Basically, when you send across the model, you can check to see if some of the model's properties have values or not. For example, if the model.Name of the request is null or an empty string, you can ignore it using the if statement and String.IsNullOrEmpty check.

Comment: That's a great answer, and now I know you understand what I want to accomplish in the end... :) But they way I want to do it is "automatically", without writing those null checks. For example, can I use Mapper to identify what properties are present in the request and then only update those properties? That way, properties that are not present don't get set to null. Get me?

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it includes a mapper implementation. You would still need to explicitly specify the condition statements in the mapping profile, like it's shown in the DogProfile class, but it would declutter the UpdateDog ActionResult method when updating.

Comment: Also I found this link that shows generic null/empty checks for properties in a class. This might be helpful too: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147856/generic-null-empty-check-for-each-property-of-a-class

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier and more automatic way to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDog(Dog model)
{


if(!ModelState.IsValid)
      return View(model);

  var dbDog = await db.Dogs.SingleAsync(x => x.DogId = model.DogId);

  // this will only update the properties that were posted
  await TryUpdateModel(dbDog);

  await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

  return View(model);
}
```